# relacionamento python no neo4j

Tags: python, postgresql, nosql

Tenho o seguinte codigo em que estou migrando um banco de dados relacional para o neo4j. Fiz um nó pra cada sensor de latitude e longitude e um nó distinto pra cada precipitação registrada no meu banco de dados.

```
    db = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474",username="neo4j", password="12345")
conn = psycopg2.connect("\
    dbname='bdTrmmTest'\
    user='postgres'\
    host='127.0.0.1'\
    password='1234'\
    ");
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT latitude, longitude, gid FROM pontos")  
records = c.fetchall() #pega todos os resultados do select e armazena em uma tupla
#cria todos os sensores os latitude e longitute
sensorlatlong = db.labels.create("Latitude/Longitude")
for i in records:
    s = db.nodes.create(latitude=i[0],longitutde=i[1])
    sensorlatlong.add(s)

#cria os nos de precipitacao
e.execute("SELECT precipitacaoh, gidgeo_fk FROM historico GROUP BY precipitacaoh")
records2 = e.fetchall()
sensorprecip = db.labels.create("Precipitacao")
for i in records:
    s2 = db.nodes.create(precipitacao=i[0])
    sensorprecip.add(s2)

#cria as relacoes entre precipitacao e sensor latitude e longitude
```

Agora quero que cada sensor latitude e longitude que marcou alguma dessas precipitações, tenha um relacionamento MARCOU com cada nó de precipitação que ele marcou.

Estou pensando em fazer um laço do tipo:

```
#cria as relacoes entre precipitacao e sensor latitude e longitude     
for i in records:
    for j in records2:
        if(i[2] == j[1]):
            s.relationships.create("MARCOU",s2)
```

Mas não sei se está certo, e o banco de dados é muito grande. Alguma sugestão?